# First program call over console after build very slow

Tags: c#, build, console

I developped a C# application to encrypt / decrypt files using Rijndael (AES) encryption method. I have one library (RijndaelLib) containing all the functionality and in order to use it I have 2 extra Projects, one Graphic User Interface (RijndaelGUI) and one Command Line Interface (RijndaelCLI). After I build the solution and I call RijndaelCLI.exe with arguments over the console, the first call is extremely slow (16s before anything happens) for no apparent reason. The following calls are very fast as expected.

When I start the RijndaelGUI.exe I don't have this "slowness" even though it is calling the exact same RijndaelLib library. And I also see from the timestamp in my log, that the program is not "waiting" anywhere during execution but it really looks like the starting itself is very slow.

I use Nugget packages log4net and CommandLine but I'm pretty sure it is not the reason because I had the same behaviour before I included them.

How do I get the first program call to behave faster after the build?

Comment: Have you tried logging which method takes most of the time? Here is a easy to use library for benchmarking: https://www.nuget.org/packages/BenchmarkDotNet/

Comment: I log my first Information with timestamp directly in the `Main()` method, when it is started I can see that everything runs as fast as expected, but between the time I press enter in the console and the time it gets in the `Main()` method there is a 16 second gap

Comment: The first execution includes the time that the Just In Time (JIT) compiler spends converting the code from Microsoft's Intermediary Language (MSIL) into the native executable machine code of whatever machine you're running the code on. All subsequent calls are re-using that already compiled code. There's also initial memory allocation to consider, and in more complex examples there's disk/memory buffering, network connection and authentication, results caching etc etc that can make a more real-world algorithm perform more slowly on the initial run for reasons not always apparent.